# Restart after nothing happend for certain time

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, settimeout, restart

I would like to set a function in every frame, that restarts the Flash-Application after nothing happend (MouseMove) for 30 Seconds. 
I am new to AS3 and would be happy for any idea and maybe some snippets.

Can you help me

Comment: Hi. Especially it is an AIR Application which I want to to reload from the server. I think that would be much easier then to reinitialize all content and data structures, isn' it? There are also many png sequenzes (little animations i did) which are going bugy after some goes. Do you have any suggestions? I can close the App with fscommand("quit") - is there something like that? I am new to this - please be 
patient.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about AS3.
But I have done it in javascript.

1. First, create a global variable.
2. Increment variable value on noAction and if the mouse moves set it to 0.
3. Check that variable for required value to initiate your function or any other event.

Comment: How can I compare the Mouse Move?